# Php метод GetGridFS() не найден!

Tags: php, mongodb

Монго установил, с колекциями и документами работает, смотрю через робомонго все есть.

Но вот задача появилась сохранять файлы в базе. Нашел готовые примеры кучу, все уже перепробовал,

Пишет что не знает что такое GetGridFS()

$m = new MongoDB\Client("адрессервера....");
$db = $m->selectDB("local");

// Get the users collection
//$c_faq = $db->faq;

// GridFS.   Вот тут говорит что нет такого метода!
$grid = $db->getGridFS();

// The file's location in the File System
$filename = "imagen1.png";

// Note metadata field & filename field
$storedfile = $grid->storeFile($path . $filename,
         array("metadata" => array("filename" => $filename),
         "filename" => $filename));

// Return newly stored file's Document ID
echo $storedfile;

Comment: А можете приложить саму ошибку, которую отдаёт PHP?

Comment: Да запросто) http://prntscr.com/bz2zrx
Только похоже @Мелкий прав, видимо выпилили gridFS из нового модуля.... что делать хз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С доступом к монге из PHP сейчас откровенный бардак. Есть расширение [`mongo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) и есть расширение [`mongodb`](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php). Одно `deprecated` и в PHP 7 уже отсутствует, другое якобы живое, функциональное от слова никак и требующее для работы какую-нибудь обёртку.

Вот в этот бардак вы и вляпались. `MongoDB\Client` - это как раз [обёртка](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/) над новым `mongodb` расширением. Из документации:

> Support for GridFS is forthcoming.

Т.е. `GridFS` оно не умеет сейчас вообще никак. Всё ещё, уже почти год от выхода PHP 7, где старый mongo уже не работает.

А `getGridFS` - это из старого расширение `mongo`. И оно `GridFS` умеет, зато не умеет PHP 7. Зачем разработчикам этих модулей так делать и сразу дропать поддержку более функционального модуля, не предоставив замену функционала - не знаю. Возможно, в PHP 7 сильно изменились необходимые интерфейсы для расширений и не нашлось желающих адаптировать старый код.

Что с этим делать:

- гуглить другие обёртки над расширением `mongodb`, которые всё-таки осилили gridfs - гуглить нетривиально из-за мешанины одинаковых названий, пробовал только что, вылезают ссылки на старое расширение;
- написать свой патч, реализующий-таки GridFS и пропихнуть его в `mongo-php-library`. Вам будет много кто благодарен;
- сидеть на PHP 5.6 и `mongo` (к счастью, `mongo` и `mongodb` хотя бы не конфликтуют между собой и могут работать одновременно). PHP 5.6 LTS, исправления безопасности ещё два года будет получать;
- делать какие-нибудь индивидуальные обходные манёвры.

Comment: Спасибо! я так и думал чето тут не чисто.
Но вопрос в том, что у меня следующий конфиг
php 5.5.9 и я установил все по инструкции с сайта php
появился модуль mongodb.so

А можно как то проще, установить старое расширение где его взять?
Я просто хз как писать этот патч, врядли осилю

Comment: Может действительно как то проще раздобыть старое расширение? Кинуть его в php/lib и подключить?
А то я уже устал неделю хожу по форумам и не понимаю чеэто у меня не работает... 
Я бы с радостью разработал патч, если б знал как это

Comment: ооо! я могу по этой инструкции поставить старое расширение??
http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php
щас буду пробовать

Comment: Да, старое расширение mongo ставится как любое другое PECL-расширение. Одновременно с mongodb уживаются нормально, проверено.

Comment: Спасиб еще раз, все заработало на старом модуле.
Подскажи, работаю с файлом, сохраняю файл вот так
Сохраняю еще дополнительные поля
$storedfile = $grid->storeFile($path . $filename, array("filename" => $filename, "fileSize" => filesize($path . $filename), "mineType" => $mineType));
Как эти поля получить???
Вот так я получаю файл
 $image = $gridFS->findOne($filename);
А как получить дополнительные мета данные

Comment: Не подскажу, к сожалению. Не сталкивался и в мануале не вижу чего-нибудь релевантного.